# Can't style link

Tags: css

Well this is a silly question I believe, but I've been looking everywhere for a solution and I can't find one.
I can't individually style that link shown in the screenshots. I've tried css selectors, I've read about styling 'a hrefs', nothing worked for me. I believe the problem lies within the '::before'. You can check it here: `lucrebem.com.br/blog/emponline/38-tenha-seu-proprio-site-de-empregos-gratuitamente` [image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seems you need a straightforward selector like `.category-name a { my style props }`. You can also use `!important` if other selectors are overriding yours.

Comment: that website doesn't like addblocker, I wouldn't go to that link.

Comment: Post some code .

Comment: @jfeferman I was trying something like this `article-info > category-name.a  { color:#000000 }`

Comment: Or `article-info > category-name a  { color:#000000 }`

Comment: The website has an antiblock, but this can be resolved by adding an exception to your adblock client.

Comment: Perhaps you are shortening your selector for brevity sake. To be sure, class selectors always start with a period as in `.article-info .category-name a {color:black;}`

Comment: @jfeferman Your answer solved it.

Comment: Can you post it as reply please?

Comment: @user013314 Answer added. Glad it solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class selectors always start with a period as in

```
.article-info .category-name a {color:black;}
```

Use a selector like the above to style your link.

Here's a **[good reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)** about css selectors.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can style that link by adding this to your CSS along with your desired style:

**CSS:**

```
.article-info > .category-name > a{
  /* Style here */
}
```